# how to create associative array structure from a text file having rows and column

Tags: tcl

i have a text file which i have to read and the second column of that file is used as key of array and whenever two keys are same i have to store that into same array of that key.

```
set filename "net.txt"
set fh [open $filename r]

while {[gets $fh data] >= 0 } {
  set x [lrange $data 1 1]

  set ntp($x) {} 


  if [info exists x]{

    append ntp($x) $data

  } else {

    set ntp($x) $data

  }
}


close $fh

foreach index [array names ntp] {

  puts "$index:$ntp($index) \n"

}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

You're close. But you should be using `lappend` instead of `append` (so you can separate the lines you accumulate) and you can simplify by using the fact that both `append` and `lappend` will happily make the element for you if it didn't exist.

Separately, you are using `lrange` to extract a single element (the `lindex` operation is more likely what you need) and you are treating the data as if it is a well-formed Tcl list. The latter is potentially awkward, but depends very much on what your data really is.

```
while {[gets $fh data] >= 0} {
    # Ignore blank lines too
    if {$data ne ""} {
        set x [lindex $data 1]
        lappend ntp($x) $data
    }
}
```

That's better!

Comment: Try using `parray ntp` to print the output. It's a debugging tool (and a very helpful supplied procedure).

Comment: can you help me how to create a function to show the content of above array (ntp) by passing key as argument